# Database Login Failed, Mysql, html, and php

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysql-error-1045

I am trying to work on getting better at making HTML forms using PHP and Mysql databases so I decided to make a little mock-up website to do some experiments and things like that.

I decided that the first thing I would need to do was to create a login and register page for users who want to sign on to the website. I had no idea how to do this so I did a little research online and I found some pre-built scripts that would do exactly what I wanted to do. In the end I decided to go with this script: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-registration-form.html

On my website (hosted with hostgator using cPanel) I set up a Mysql database called ljbaumer_gifts (website is a gift website) and I added a table with 2 columns. The first one a login column which was set to int with auto increment and 25 characters. The second one is a password one which was set to var_char and 25 characters.

I filled in all of the information on the setup scripts from the website I linked to earlier  completely correctly but every single time I try to register I get this error code:

> Database Login failed! Please make sure that the DB login credentials provided are correct
>   mysqlerror:Access denied for user 'ljbamer_root'@'my_server_adress' (using password: YES)
>   Database login failed!

I used an account that has complete privileges on my server but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have trouble with connection string.
In your Hostgator Control panel You have to follow this steps.

1. Create Database
2. Create User
3. Add User To Database
4. Give a user permissions to a database
5. Save your settings.

Now u can use Created Database, And User Credentials of USER assigned to your database.
Things will work fine afterwards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your database credentials are wrong or the MySQL user isn't set up properly. Don't use your cPanel username / password, you need to use your MySQL username / password, which is granted access to the necessary database (you can set this in cPanel).

Answer (score 0):

usually you need 4 parameters, the first being the host and usually just setting it to `localhost` will work.

The next is the database user and the name of the database which tend to be the same in a lot of cases.

From looking at your question this could be `ljbaumer_gifts` and finally you need your password which I have no idea what it could be but if you followed the steps provided by the other answers I think you should be able to get it, even if you have to delete what you have already and start it again.

```
 // Connect to database server
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Generic Error Message');

// Select database
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

Comment: Ok so I think that I figured out my problem but I don't know how to solve it. The script that I used says it will automatically create the tables for me but when I look at the PHPmyadmin on my cPanel I cannot find the tables that it created. I think that it just doesn't have the power to connect or something. I think this might be a little complicated to solve on stackoverflow but if somebody who knows what to do could help me out it would be great if you could send me a PM with your gTalk information and I can talk to you about it!

Comment: I think you should try creating the table first of all in PHPmyadmin and then try a simple query out and make sure everything works as expected and then try and implement it in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

/*hostname*/'**localhost**',

Don't set the hostname to your website host information, instead use **localhost** because the database is running on your website as a **localhost**.
Cheers